# Groupby several columns and take the sum based off of categorical values within a column (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to groupby several columns and take the sum based off of categorical values within a column.

**Data**

```
name    size    type
AA      9385    FALSE
AA      9460    FALSE
AA      9572    TRUE
AA      9680    
BB      10      TRUE
BB      10      TRUE
BB      20      FALSE
BB      20      FALSE
```

**Desired**

```
name    size    type
AA      9572    TRUE
AA      18845   FALSE
AA      9680    
BB      20      TRUE
BB      40      FALSE
BB
```

**Doing**

```
df = df.groupby('name').agg({'size': 'sum', 'type': lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()})
```

However, this appears to have removed Null values. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dropna=False` in groupby:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'type'], dropna=False, as_index=False)['size'].sum()
```

Output:

```
  name   type   size
0   AA  False  18845
1   AA   True   9572
2   AA    NaN   9680
3   BB  False     40
4   BB   True     20
```